# how to insert the content of a text widget into a sqlite database

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, textbox

all.

I am trying to make a takinter entry form to populate an incident database.

I have managed to enter the entry boxes and the check boxes using `entrywidgetvariable.get()` , but I don't find any proper way to insert the text from the textbox.

could anyone enlighten me?

> **Copy from comment**:
>
> ```
> c.execute("INSERT INTO Incidents (Datestamp, Description, Place, Latitude, Longitude, Precision, Intimidation, Destruction, Burglary, Carjacking, Theft) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", \ 
> (date, description.get(),place.get(),latitude.get(), longitude.get(), precision.get(), intimidation1.get(),destruction2.get(), burglary3.get(), carjacking4.get(), theft5.get() )) 
> con.commit()
> ```

Comment: You can use [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module.

Comment: I do, but I didn't find a way to insert the content of a text box.

Comment: I am trying to do the same with the textbox. Something similar to decription.get(), but with the multiline text entered in a text widget

Comment: For `Text` widget, you need to use `description.get(1.0, 'end')` to get all the text.

Comment: where "description" is the name of the Text widget?

Comment: Yes.  Just an example showing how to get the content of `Text` widget.

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: It works in my [sample code](https://ibb.co/sm07yYW).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a syntax problem on my side. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that works to enter thje text data:

```
date = datetime.date(int(year.get()),int(month.get()), int(day.get()))
 narratif=T.get("1.0","end-1c")


 c.execute("""INSERT INTO Incidents
   (Datestamp, Description, Place, Latitude, Longitude, Precision, Intimidation, Destruction, Burglary,
   Carjacking, Theft, Assault, Sexualassault, Abduction, Homicide, Shooting, Explosive,  Narrative)
   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""", (date, description.get(),place.get(),latitude.get(), longitude.get(), precision.get(), intimidation1.get(),destruction2.get(), burglary3.get(), carjacking4.get(), theft5.get(), assault6.get(), sexualassault7.get(), abduction8.get(), homicide9.get(), shooting10.get(), explosive11.get(), narratif))
```